# Receive RaisePropertyChanged in Viewmodel (MVVM Light)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I got this Data Structure:

12 Measurements, each Measurement contains 1-x Cells, each Cell contains 1-x Stations. The Amount of Cells/Stations is the same for each Measurement.

Therefore i have a Measurement, a Cell and a Station Class. Each of these 3 implement the `ObservableObject` Class.

In my View i create a Itemscontrol for each Measurement to display all Cells of a Measurement. Each Item contains an Itemscontrol to display all the Stations in Textboxes.

Now i need a 13th Measurement in which i calculate the sums from each station across all Measurements. (*Station 1 from Cell 1 from all 12 Measurement*).

Currently my Viewmodel only contains a Observable Collection with the 12 Basic Measurements.

How can i detect if a Value of a Station-Textbox is changed and what Station has been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could latch onto the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051) event for each Station in the ViewModel. This is an event handler in `ObservableObject` that is triggered whenever a property is modified (*part of the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface*).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the UI to refresh not only when an item is added/removed from the collection, but also when an item raise [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx), use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) instead of an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).
It will raise the [ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742.aspx) event, which you can listen to for additional information.

Don't listen directly to PropertyChanged unless you want some .Net event hell.

HTH,

Bab.